# Where is type_info object stored?

Tags: c++

I read from "*Inside The C++ Object Model*" that the type_info object is often stored at the first slot of the virtual table. However, I iterated the members in the virtual table:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "Base::f" << endl; }
    virtual void g() { cout << "Base::g" << endl; }
    virtual void h() { cout << "Base::h" << endl; }
};

typedef void(*Fun)(void);

Base b;

(Fun)*((int*)*(int*)(&b)+0); // Base::f()
(Fun)*((int*)*(int*)(&b)+1); // Base::g()
(Fun)*((int*)*(int*)(&b)+2); // Base::h()
```

As you see from the last three lines, I can't find type_info at all.

Comment: what hinders the compiler to put it at -1 ? check the generated assembler code when you access type_info...

Comment: There is http://stackoverflow.com/q/6258559/196561 the copy of description of all vtable/vtabletable and type_info pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no cross-compiler way to get at the `type_info` from the address of an object. Nor would you expect there to be; the way to get a `type_info` is using a specific C++ keyword: `typeid`.

Comment: So is type_info actually stored anywhere? I think most of the time the compiler knows enough information so that typeid(whatever) can be optimized out at compile time.

Comment: Yes, a `type_info` is "stored somewhere". It is a real object that the compiler must create storage for. But more than likely, it is stored in global data, since `type_info` objects must exist until the end of execution.

Comment: @Nicol yeah I think that too, since you can't copy them (`type_info`s)but you can return references to them which indicates they exist somewhere independently.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
class Base {
    public:
        virtual void f() { cout << "Base::f" << endl; }
        virtual void g() { cout << "Base::g" << endl; }
        virtual void h() { cout << "Base::h" << endl; }
};

int main(void)
{
    typedef void(*Fun)(void);
    Fun pFun = NULL;
    Base b;

    pFun = (Fun)(*((long *)(*((long *)(&b))) + 0));
    pFun();//Base::f()
    pFun = (Fun)(*((long *)(*((long *)(&b))) + 1));
    pFun();//Base::g()
    pFun = (Fun)(*((long *)(*((long *)(&b))) + 2));
    pFun();//Base::h()

    type_info *base_type = (type_info *)(*((long *)(*((long *)(&b))) - 1));
    cout << "typeinfo is:" << base_type->name() << endl;

    cout << "the result of typeid(Base).name():" << typeid(Base).name() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
Base::f
Base::g
Base::h
typeinfo is:4Base
the result of typeid(Base).name():4Base
```

I use GCC 4.9.2 and my system is 64bit. so I use `long` instead of `int`.

> type_info object is often stored at the first slot of the virtual
>   table.

This is wrong I think.
*type_info object is often stored before the virtual table.*
`(long *)(*((long *)(&b)))`:this is the address of virtual table
`(long *)(*((long *)(&b))) - 1`:this is the address of type_info object
so you see the result of the `base_type->name()` is `4Base`. The result is the same as using `typeid`.The `4` in `4Base` is the number of letters in your class name(`Base`).[more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465872/why-does-typeid-name-return-weird-characters-using-gcc-and-how-to-make-it-prin)

ALSO:
when you complie the code with `-fdump-class-hierarchy`,you could see the `Vtable for Base`

```
Vtable for Base
Base::_ZTV4Base: 5u entries
0     (int (*)(...))0
8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI4Base)
16    (int (*)(...))Base::f
24    (int (*)(...))Base::g
32    (int (*)(...))Base::h
```

You could see `_ZTI4Base` is before `Base::f`
use `c++filt _ZTI4Base` would output `typeinfo for Base`

Comment: I'm not even sure if this is an answer or a question. I have no idea how to (or even if I should) flag this.

Comment: OK,I deleted the question.

Answer (score -1):

type_info is available only if you enable RTTI(runtime type information) compilation flag for some compilers.

Comment: Note that not "enabling" the RTTI stops your compiler from being conformant with the standard. While many compilers do support turning of RTTI as an extension, the _language_ does not.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: so for testing purpose only, to see address of type_info into vtable (as most of compiler implement it) you need RTTI enabled.